# The function $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb R $ defined by $f(x) := 1/x$ is not uniformly continuous, but it is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

The function $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb R $ defined by $f(x) := 1/x$ is not uniformly continuous, but it is continuous.
Proof: given $\epsilon > 0$, then for $\epsilon > \mid 1/x - 1/y \mid$ to hold we must have

$\epsilon > \mid 1/x - 1/y \mid = \frac{\mid y-x \mid }{\mid  xy \mid } = \frac{\mid y-x\mid }{xy}$

$\mid x -y \mid < xy\epsilon$

Therefore to satisfy the definition of uniform continuity we would have to have $\delta \leq xy\epsilon$ for all $x, y$ in (0,1). but that would mean that $\delta \leq 0$ Therefore there is no single $\delta >0$

I don't understand $\delta \leq 0$  part... why it is less than or equal to 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\delta \leq xy \epsilon,  \forall x,y \in (0,1)$$

Fix $y=\frac12, \epsilon=2$

We have $$\delta \leq x, \forall x \in (0,1)$$

Such positive number $\delta$ doesn't exists, if it exists, then we can choose $x=\frac{\delta}{2}$.

Hence the conclusion of $\delta \leq 0$

Comment: sorry I still don't understand why such $\delta$ doesn't exist ?

Comment: if $\delta >0$ and $\delta \leq \frac{\delta}{2}$, then divide $\delta$ on both sides, we have $1 \leq \frac12$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhh this is what I want . Thank you now I got it

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$, then if we let $\varepsilon=1$, there is $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y\in (0,1),\ |x-y|<\delta$, we have $|1/x-1/y|<\varepsilon=1.$ (Without loss of generality, we assume $\delta<1$)

If we consider $x=\delta/2$ and $y=\delta/4$, then $|x-y|=|\delta/4|<\delta$, but $$
|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|=|\frac{2}{\delta}-\frac{4}{\delta}|=\frac{2}{\delta}>2>1=\varepsilon. 
$$
The contradiction implies that $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1).$

Answer (score 0):

If it were uniformly continuous, then corresponding to $\epsilon = 1$ in the definition of uniform continuity, we can take $\delta > 0$ so that $|x-y| < \delta \implies |\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}| < 1$. Since $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $[\delta,1-\delta]$, there is some $C > 0$ so that $|\frac{1}{x}| < C$ on $[\delta,1-\delta]$ (this follows from compactness). For $x \in (0,\delta)$, we have $|\frac{1}{x}| < |\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\delta}|+|\frac{1}{\delta}| < C+1$. Similarly for $x \in (1-\delta,1)$. Therefore, we get $|\frac{1}{x}| < C+1$ for all $x \in (0,1)$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Set $x_n=\frac{1}{n+2} , y_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$ .

For every $n \in \mathbb{N} $ we have $x_n , y_n \in (0,1) $ and $\lim |x_n-y_n|=0$  .

But $ \lim |f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=1 \neq 0 $ .

Hence not uniformly continuous .